# angularjs filter using comparator with multiple filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am attempting to make an angularjs filter. I am filtering on three attributes. the first two are comparator false and the last is comparator true. is this possible without making a custom filter?  I tried below but it throws an error.

|

```
 filter :
     {
        'PatientFullName' : vm.headerService.searchText,
        'Archived' : vm.headerService.Archived,
        'PhysicianID' : {vm.headerService.selectedPhysician.PhysicianID,true}
     }
```

here is the whole html

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="patient in vm.patientlist | orderBy: vm.headerService.currentSort.orderBy:vm.headerService.currentSort.sortDescending
     | filter :
     {
        'PatientFullName' : vm.headerService.searchText,
        'Archived' : vm.headerService.Archived,
        'PhysicianID' : {vm.headerService.selectedPhysician.PhysicianID,true}
     }">
```

here is the error

> angular.js:14794 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is
>   unexpected, expecting [}] at column 263 of the expression
>   [vm.patientlist | orderBy:
>   vm.headerService.currentSort.orderBy:vm.headerService.currentSort.sortDescending
>        | filter :
>        {
>           'PatientFullName' : vm.headerService.searchText,
>           'Archived' : vm.headerService.Archived,
>           'PhysicianID' : {vm.headerService.selectedPhysician.PhysicianID,true}
>        }] starting at [.headerService.selectedPhysician.PhysicianID,true}
>        }].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{vm.headerService.selectedPhysician.PhysicianID,true}` is not correct object. To perform filtering by different value of `comparator` you may chain filtering:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="patient in vm.patientlist | orderBy: vm.headerService.currentSort.orderBy:vm.headerService.currentSort.sortDescending
 | filter :
 {
    'PatientFullName' : vm.headerService.searchText,
    'Archived' : vm.headerService.Archived
 }
 | filter : 
{        
    'PhysicianID' : vm.headerService.selectedPhysician.PhysicianID
}: true">
```

But better rewrite that into controller's method. It will improve the readability:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" 
 ng-repeat="patient in vm.patientlist | 
            orderBy: vm.headerService.currentSort.orderBy
                   : vm.headerService.currentSort.sortDescending
           |filter : vm.myFilteringMethod">
```